# Java AWT drawing tiles laves gap

Tags: java, graphics, awt, rendering, tile

I am trying to make a tile based game in Java and I have noticed a problem with the drawing. There is about a one pixel gap between some of the tiles and I am not sure what is causing it.

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbJ2B.png]

Here is my code so far:

Main class:

```
package Game.main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static JFrame window;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(1280, 720);
        window.setTitle("Game");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Game game = new Game();
        window.add(game);
    }
}
```

Game class:

```
package Game.main;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Game.tile.Tile;

public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public Game() {
        start();
    }

    boolean running = false;

    int width,height;

    ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void paint(Graphics g1) {
        //cast to graphics2d
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)g1;
        //fill background
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        //draw tiles
        for(int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
            tiles.get(i).render(g, width, height);
        }
    }

    private void start() {
        Thread gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
        //create start tiles
        for(int x = 0; x < 1000; x+=10) {
            for(int y = 700; y < 1000; y+=20) {
                Tile tile = new Tile(x, y);
                tiles.add(tile);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while(running) {
            //get window width and height
            requestFocus();
            width = Main.window.getWidth();
            height = Main.window.getHeight();
            //redraw current frame
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Tile class:

```
package Game.tile;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Tile {
    public int x,y;
    public int w,h;
    public Tile(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = 10;
        this.h = this.w*2;
    }
    public void render(Graphics2D g, int width, int height) {
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(this.x*width/1000, this.y*height/1000, this.w*width/1000, this.h*height/1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have magic numbers in your "Game" class:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 1000; x+=10) {
        for(int y = 700; y < 1000; y+=20) {
            Tile tile = new Tile(x, y);
            tiles.add(tile);
        }
```

And you have more magic numbers in your Tile class:

```
    this.w = 10;
    this.h = this.w*2;
}
public void render(Graphics2D g, int width, int height) {
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillRect(this.x*width/1000, this.y*height/1000, this.w*width/1000, this.h*height/1000);
}
```

You are also going to get rounding when you use:

```
  x * width / 1000
```

So the "x" value you get when painting will not always be a multiple of 10 like you expect. This is probably why you get the gaps between tiles.

You need to remove the magic numbers from multiple classes. For example the `Tile` class should be self contained. It should be able to paint itself without any magic numbers. All the information should be passed to the class in the constructor.

For example:

```
//public Tile(int x, int y) {
public Tile(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
```

Then in the painting logic you can use:

```
//public void render(Graphics2D g, int width, int height) {
public void render(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    //g.fillRect(this.x*width/1000, this.y*height/1000, this.w*width/1000, this.h*height/1000);
    g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
}
```

And in you Game class when you create the Tile you would use:

```
//Tile tile = new Tile(x, y);
Tile tile = new Tile(x, y, 10, 20);
```

Now the `Game` class fully controls the size and number of tiles. The `Tile` class just paints itself and doesn't worry about the size of the Game panel.

Of course you have to make sure you use reasonable values when creating the tiles:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 1000; x+=10) {
        for(int y = 700; y < 1000; y+=20) {
```

Why would the "y" variable start at 700 when the height of the frame is only 720?